# Look for coincidences in two arrays and create another one without the items that are repeated

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am creating an app that gives rewards to the users, so they can obtain randomly complements to their avatars. I have a list of items that they can win and another list of items that they already have. My problem is that I don't know how to look for a match between the two arrays and create another without the ones that they already have.

```
var availableAvatar =['Csimple','Calien','Ccosmonaut','CgreenAereal','ChappyBirthday']
var userAvatars=['Ccosmonaut','ChappyBirthday']
```

I tried with the filter method but it creates an array of the matches and I don't know how to do it the other way.
What I need:

```
var possibleAward=['Csimple','Calien','CgreenAereal']
var random = avatarP[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleAward.length)];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove same Values from array of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708097/remove-same-values-from-array-of-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `filter` function is perfect for this:

```js
var availableAvatars = ['Csimple','Calien','Ccosmonaut','CgreenAereal','ChappyBirthday']
var userAvatars = ['Ccosmonaut','ChappyBirthday']
var possibleAvatars = availableAvatars.filter(x => !userAvatars.includes(x));
var randomAvatar = possibleAvatars[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleAvatars.length)];

console.log(possibleAvatars);
console.log(randomAvatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var availableAvatar =['Csimple','Calien','Ccosmonaut','CgreenAereal','ChappyBirthday']
var userAvatars=['Ccosmonaut','ChappyBirthday']

var possibleRewards = availableAvatar.filter(element => {
  return !userAvatars.includes(element);
});

console.log(possibleRewards);
```